# Why CLion doesn't mark class as class?

Tags: c++, class, clion

[image][image]When I try to write this class, it doesn't see it as class, and can't resolve class Card. What can I do with that?

```
#ifndef HAND_HPP
#define HAND_HPP

#include <iosfwd>
#include <vector>
#include "cards.hpp"

class Hand {  //it doesn't mark it as class
private:
    int maxSize;
    std::vector<Card> hand;  //Cannot resolve variable 'Card'

public:
 ***
};


#endif //HAND_HPP
```

now I can upload images, so it looks like that. 
and cards.hpp (where Card is declared) contains including of hand.hpp.

Comment: Maybe there is some problem with the `"cards.hpp"` file. Try to omit that include. Replace with `struct Card {};`.

Comment: I omitted that include and it offered me to return it.

Comment: Do you get an actual compiler error when you try to compile it? I've had problems with CLion's indexer getting confused, though not on anything this simple.

Comment: thank you all. 
we decided to change project totally. :)

Comment: " Be Warned
It is important to distinguish EAP from traditional pre-release software. Please note that the quality of EAP versions may at times be way below even usual beta standards."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `#include` the header file that contains declaration of class `Card`, or put the declaration of `Card` class above `Hand`. Compiler needs to know the complete definition (not implementation) of `Card` class, and hence any forward declaration wont appease the compiler.

Comment: cards.hpp contains declaration of class Card.

Comment: Then `card.hpp` must be including `hand.hpp`. Please try!

Comment: it was added long ago. 

and now I changed everywhere class with struct. and it didn't help.